# Regular expression for a string contains characters not in a specific set

Tags: java, regex, string, pattern-matching

I trying to determine if a string contains any characters not in a set using regular expressions in Java.

I have the following set of valid characters "@ADEFIKRVXY156".  White space characters can be ignored and can be considered valid.

The input would be a string that is a series of alpha numeric characters or a white space.  The regular expression I would like to write would have Java's  Pattern.matcher(String) return true if the inputted String contains any characters not in my valid set. If the string has some valid and some invalid characters, the entire string should be evaluated as not valid.  The only case for validity is the entire string contains characters only in the valid set.  Now each character has to be evaluated in the string against the set of valid characters,  not string matching or pattern matching.

Sample input that is valid (Java Pattern.matcher should return false):
"@", " F", " F I", "R  I"

Sample input that is not valid (Java Pattern.matcher should return true):
" 4 I", " FT", " 4 B"

Thanks for the help

Comment: Here's an absolutely lovely tool to test your regexes: http://www.regexr.com/

Answer (score 4):

Try `[@ADEFIKRVXY156\\s]*` if the empty String is valid (+ instead of * otherwise).

```
String[] valid    = { "@", " F", " F I", "R I" };
String[] notValid = { " 4 I", " FT", " 4 B" };
String pattern    = "[@ADEFIKRVXY156\\s]*";
for (String s : valid) 
    System.out.println(!s.matches(pattern));
for (String s : notValid) 
    System.out.println(!s.matches(pattern));
```

Output :

```
false
false
false
false
true
true
true
```

Answer (score 2):

It allows one or more characters which are present inside the character class,

```
[@ADEFIKRVXY156\\s]+
```

Code:

```
String[] valid    = { "@", " F", " F I", "R I" };
String[] notValid = { " 4 I", " FT", " 4 B" };
String pattern    = "[@ADEFIKRVXY156\\s]+";
for (String s : valid) 
    System.out.println(!s.matches(pattern));
for (String s : notValid) 
    System.out.println(!s.matches(pattern));
```

Comment: You need to add the anchors ^ and $ to the beginning and end respectively to make sure the input consists only of those characters: `/^[@ADEFIKRVXY156 ]+$/`

Comment: matches method don't need anchors.

Comment: you cannot specify a white space with a literal white space, you would have to use an escaped sequence like \\s

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is that (Java Pattern.matcher should return true) when is invalid and you are not going to use the match value you should use the negated character class structure `[^`

Here you have the regex:

```
.*[^@ADEFIKRVXY156\s]
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/tQ1hE7/1)

It will return true when the regex finds the first character that is not in your range.